# How to stop running process in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am calling a same function in parallel using Task.WhenAll(); and I was wondering if there is any way we can stop all threads /process if stop button is clicked? Also I do not want browser to be closed. can anyone suggest me what approach I should use?

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Runcase(List<string> products,string runnumber,string button)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var productinfo = products;
                    List<string> productids = new List<string>(productinfo);
                    var runnum = runnumber;
                    string runid = "";
                    int count = productids.Count();
                    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
                    int rawid = 0;
                     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                        {
                           tasks.Add(RunServiceAsync(productids[i], runnum,rawid));
                        }
                    
                    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                    ViewBag.completed = "Success";
                    return View();
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.productinfo = new MultiSelectList(_context.inputValuesConfigurations, "ProductID", "ProductName");
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Please enter a valid data...");
                    return View();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Comment: ``CancellationTokenSource`` You can pass token into each and then cancel them all at once

Comment: This may be helpful for you. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848606/how-to-safely-cancel-a-task-using-a-cancellationtoken-and-await-task-whenall

Comment: There is more to this problem than just a `CancellationToken` though, however its a good start

Comment: https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/
this looks quite similar to your issue, and for button you could invoke `xhr.abort()` on client side

Comment: To cancel a task and Its Children, you could create and start a cancelable task. Then, Pass a cancellation token to your user delegate and optionally to the task instance. After that, notice and respond to the cancellation request in your user delegate, once the cancellation  was requested (use the CancellationTokenSource.Cancel method), cancel the task. More detail information, see [How to: Cancel a Task and Its Children](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-task-and-its-children)

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help. I looked at the resource link you provided and it helped me.